# python using variables from another file

Tags: python, python-import

I'm new and trying to make a simple random sentence generator- 
How can I pull a random item out of a list that is stored in another .py document? 
I'm using

```
random.choice(verb_list)
```

to pull from the list. How do I tell python that verb_list is in another document?

Also it would be helpful to know what the principle behind the solution is called. I imagine it's something like 'file referencing' 'file bridging' etc..

Comment: Added the `python-import` tag, in the hopes that it will help future duplicate-closers to find this canonical.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can import the variables from the file:

**vardata.py**

```
verb_list = [x, y, z]
other_list = [1, 2, 3]
something_else = False
```

**mainfile.py**

```
from vardata import verb_list, other_list
import random

print random.choice(verb_list)
```

you can also do:

```
from vardata import *
```

to import everything from that file. Be careful with this though. You don't want to have name collisions.

Alternatively, you can just import the file and access the variables though its namespace:

```
import vardata
print vardata.something_else
```

Comment: this does not work if the variable you need imported is defined in a function. How do you get around this?

Comment: @gmonz try returning the variable from your function and import everything

Comment: @gmonz That is by design via function scoping rules. Any variables inside a function should be returned if you need to access them elsewhere. 

You can access the returned output by calling the function from the other file after importing it.

Answer (score 10):

It’s called importing.

If this is `data.py`:

```
verb_list = [
    'run',
    'walk',
    'skip',
]
```

and this is `foo.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import data
print data.verb_list
```

Then running `foo.py` will access `verb_list` from `data.py`.

---

You might want to work through the [Modules section of the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

---

If `verb_list` is stored in a script that you want to do other things too, then you will run into a problem where the script runs when all you’d like to do is import its variables. In that case the standard thing to do is to keep all of the script functionality in a function called `main()`, and then use a magic incantation:

```
verb_list = [
    'run',
    'walk',
    'skip',
]

def main():
    print 'The verbs are', verb_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now the code in `main()` won’t run if all you do is `import data`. If you’re interested, Python creator Guido van Rossum has written an article on writing more elaborate [Python `main()` functions](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829).

Comment: Note that one doesn't have to put that code in a `main()` function, it can be just put in the `if` clause.

Comment: True, but this way other modules can also access the `main` functionality of scripts when importing. I’ve updated my answer to link to an article with further elaborations.

Comment: Thank you- using main is what did the trick. I had been using import but like you said, my verb_list script would run.