# How can I include a variable to a module

Tags: python-2.7

Let's say I have a module that can open a website
a module is like this:

```
open("here is the variable from another python file")
```

so how can I include that variable to my module
I know there is mechanize module but I want to create my own module

Comment: possible duplicate of [python using variables from another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573021/python-using-variables-from-another-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import variables from a file using the following syntax.

```
from PYTHON_MODULE_FILE import *
```

You can replace `*` with the specific member(s) you want to import. `*` imports all members.