# Using variables from other python files

Tags: python

I'm having some problems with this:

I have two files: random and random2

random has this:

```
    import random2
    print(random2.verb_list)
    print(random2.x)
```

random2 has this:

```
    verb_list = ['x', 'y', 'z']
    other_list = ['1', '2', '3']
    something_else = False

    def Main():
        global x
        x = 1
        print(verb_list)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Main()
```

It gives me this error when I run random:

```
AttributeError: module 'random2' has no attribute 'x'
```

Is there a way so I can call the variable x in random?
I have python3

Comment: Try actually declaring `x` outside your function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python using variables from another file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573021/python-using-variables-from-another-file)

Comment: @WayneWerner I've tried that and it works. But what I want to do is change the x value in a function. Is it possible?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yup, I searched that and used part of the code, but still, it doesn't help.

Comment: @luistripa You've got to provide an actual error description if you want help. "I looked at the right way to do it that works for everyone else but it doesn't help me." doesn't do anything for anyone involved. What are you trying to do, what _exactly_ have you tried in order to accomplish it, and what errors, if any, are you getting?

Comment: So, I'm trying to call a variable (x) in a file (random2) from another file (random) and I want to print that variable's value via file random, the problem is that it tells me that x is not defined in random2 which it actually is! If I put x outside function Main() I can print it but my objective is to define its value inside the function and then print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `x` is not created until the `Main()` function is run. Importing a module means that `__name__` isn't set to `__main__`, so the function is never executed.

You must execute the Main() function. Put `random2.Main()` in the file `random.py` after the import line.

The name `random` is a very poor name for a module, since it collides with the standard python `random` module. It can create unexpected side effects.

Comment: Sorry about the file name...it was the first thing that came to my head. Anyway, it worked!