# Python modules/import data?

Tags: python-2.7, variables, import, module

I have a two python files I am working with.

In cryp.py I have:

```
def test():
    test = raw_input("> ")
```

In  cryptek.py I have:

```
import cryp
What is your name?
cryp.test
print "To be sure your name is: " + test
```

It errrs out as "test is not defined" How do I make it get the test variable from cryp.py?

Comment: Have you tried `import cryp`?

Comment: Yes I already have import cryp at the top I'll be editing it in

Comment: Is `test` a reserved keyword in Python?

Comment: I am not sure, I also tried it with the word pizza to make sure, same issue

Comment: I believe test is a reserved keyword. Cannot guarantee this is correct though. BTW pizza is the best.

Comment: I used pizza because I knew it wasnt a reserved keyword. :P

Answer (score 0):

(I have Python 3.6.1) So i solved it but not exactly as you asked. Hopefully this gives you a start:

cryptek:

```
from cryp import *
print("To be sure your name is: " + test)
```

cryp:

```
name = input ("> ")
def test():
    pass
test()
```

Works perfect. The issue is where the definitions come in.

Do you need this to work with definitions?

Comment: I've tried that gmons, it still gives me "test isn't defined" I use import cryp already

Comment: does these posts help at all?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573021/python-using-variables-from-another-file

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file

Comment: No it didn't actually. I looked at that before posting this question, as it is technically one of the rules.

Comment: Got it. I am going to help you solve this, but it may take until the end of the day as I am at work right now.

Comment: It usually takes a bit to solve issues when coding either way, so I usually take my time, no hurry :P

Comment: gomz test needs to be input by the user test = raw_input("> ")

Comment: @TheCryptek ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here. You added the `import` statement. The test() function needs to return something. If not, it will return `None`. Also, `cryp.test` is a function object, while `cryp.test()` is a call to the function.

The error message that is not in the question tells about this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cryptek.py", line 4, in <module>
    print "To be sure your name is: " + cryp.test()
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

cryp.py

```
def test():
    test = raw_input("> ")
    return test
```

cryptek.py

```
import cryp
print "What is your name?"
cryp.test
print "To be sure your name is: " + cryp.test()

C:>python cryptek.py
What is your name?
> asdf
To be sure your name is: asdf
```

Comment: After adding this, it is now prompting me with test = raw_input("> ") twice, meaning I have to enter a name twice before it continues on ._.

Comment: That isn't my error... here is my error
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cryptek.py", line 4, in <module>
    print "\nTo be sure, your name is: " + name
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

`

Comment: @TheCryptek - Sorry, yes, you had that error message. The `cannot concatenate` message is the one you would get next, until `()` was added to `test` to make it a function call.

Comment: I have it as cryp.test()

Comment: I'm not worried about the cannot concatenate error, that I can fix easily, right now I'm trying to solve my current easy, pulling test from cryp.py

Comment: I have, but then I get greeted by two prompts to enter a name, when you should only be asked once ._. run it to see what I'm talking about.