# Python drama with variable

Tags: python, variables, import, set

in python I have this set of variable

variable.py

```
#--------------Project 1--------------#
ip_server = '10.10.55.98'
username = 'user_1'
distro = 'debian'

#--------------Project 2--------------#
ip_server = '10.10.55.96'
username = 'user_2'
distro = 'opensuse'

#--------------Project 3--------------#
ip_server = '10.10.55.95'
username = 'user_3'
distro = 'ubuntu'
```

In the script main.py I just want to import variable of **Project 2**, how to this?

main.py

```
from variable import *

ho_to_import_variable_of_project2?
```

thanks to all for answers anche time to dedicate my question

Comment: Does `from variable import *` not work for you? By the way, you are just redefining `ip_server`, `username`, and `distro` 3 times so at the end you will only have 3 variables, not 9.

Comment: You do not have separate variables for projects 1, 2, 3 – you overwrite the same variables each time, and at the end you only have the values for project 3.

Comment: Is your question how to **import** something (because you already seem to know that) or how to create **different variables** for each project?

Comment: Potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573021/python-using-variables-from-another-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption that using comments to "separate" the variables to logical groups means anything to the interpreter is wrong. All you are really doing is overwriting the same variables.

Also, [avoid using `import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

Instead, I'd use a dictionary:

```py
data = {
    'Project 1': {
        'ip_server': '10.10.55.98',
        'username': 'user_1',
        'distro': 'debian'
    },
    'Project 2': {
        'ip_server': '10.10.55.96',
        'username': 'user_2',
        'distro': 'opensuse'
    },
    'Project 3': {
        'ip_server': '10.10.55.95',
        'username': 'user_3',
        'distro': 'ubuntu'
    }
}
```

then use it:

```py
from variable import data

print(data['Project 1']['ip_server'])
```

will output

```
10.10.55.98
```

At this point you might as well use an external JSON file as a config file but that is behind the scope of this question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list  and dictionary for each project like below:

```
variable.py

project1 = [{'ip_server' :'10.10.55.98', 'username':'user_1', 'distro' : 'debian'}]
project2 = [{'ip_server' :'10.10.55.95', 'username':'user_2', 'distro' : 'opensuse'}]
project3 = [{'ip_server' :'10.10.55.96', 'username':'user_3', 'distro' : 'ubuntu'}]
```

And in `main.py`

```
from variable import project1
```